# e.target.dataset doesn't give the same value twice - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, flask

I'm trying to get the id assigned at these html buttons, but when I read the value before it gives me the right value, but when I'm in the implementation of the function, it always read the value 1.

Following the html snippet:

```
<section class="section-products">
        <div class="products">
            {% for d in data %}
            <div class="container">
                {{d.name}}
                <div class="descriptionProduct">
                    {{d.description}}
                    <div class="quantityProduct">
                        <button class="productButton" title="add to cart">add to cart</button>
                        <div class="modal">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <span class="close-button">&times;</span>
                                <h2>Choose the desired quantity: </h2>
                                <input type="number" id="numOfProduct" min="1" max="3">
                                <button class="confirmButton" data-id="{{ d.id }}"> Confirm </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </section>
```

and the following is the Javascript snippet:

```
let confirmButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".confirmButton"); 
for(let i=0; i<confirmButtons.length; i++){
    console.log(confirmButtons[i].dataset['id']); 
    confirmButtons[i].onclick = (e) => {
        const idproduct = e.target.dataset['id'];
        console.log(idproduct);
```

In the first console.log everything is as it should be but in the second attempt to read the value, it always reads the same value, 1.
I really don't know how to fix this because when I run the code there's no error, it just doesn't work as I expected.

EDIT:
My code HTML right now is edited like this:

```
<button type="button" class="confirmButton" data-idproduct="{{ d.idproduct }}" > Confirm </button>
```

and Javascript like this:

```
function addProduct(ev) {
const id = ev.currentTarget.dataset['idproduct'];
console.log(ev);
fetch('/shop/add', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        'mail': 'none',
        'idproduct' : id
    }),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
}).then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
}).then(function (jsonResponse) {
    console.log(jsonResponse);
});
}

let confirmButtons = document.querySelectorAll(" .confirmButton");
confirmButtons.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", addProduct));
```

And it still gives me the value 1 no matter what. Following is the image of the console from chrome [image: console]

Comment: Don't put functions inside loops

Comment: Don't create duplicated IDs. Never use/create the same repeated IDs inside for loops.

Comment: Never use `Event.target` (unless you really know what you're doing) Use `Event.currentTarget` instead.

Comment: The problem is about the data-id attribute, not the id attribute. But Roko C. is right, you should never have duplicated Ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understood what is really the problem in my code. After some deep thinking, I guess that the instance of the .modal class it always reference to the first instance. I don't know for certain if it's because it has been created only one instance or something.
I won't think for a solution, I'll just change approach, for what I have to do it doesn't matter how it's done.
I thank everyone who tried to help me.

Answer (score 1):

**Your code actually works.** I think that your data-id value is wrong in the DOM, making a console log '1' every time.

Or maybe, you should be more specific when selecting your confirm button here: `document.querySelectorAll(".confirmButton");`

Because there's maybe another .confirmButton somewhere in your page that you are selecting. You could try:

```
 document.querySelectorAll(".section-products .descriptionProduct .confirmButton");
```

**Here is an example with your code showing that it works:**

```js
let confirmButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".confirmButton"); 
for(let i=0; i<confirmButtons.length; i++){
    console.log(confirmButtons[i].dataset['id']); 
    confirmButtons[i].onclick = (e) => {
        const idproduct = e.target.dataset['id'];
        console.log({idproduct});
    }
}
```

```html
<section class="section-products">
        <div class="products">
           
            <div class="container">
                hello
                <div class="descriptionProduct">
                    description
                    <div class="quantityProduct">
                        <button class="productButton" title="add to cart">add to cart</button>
                        <div class="modal">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <span class="close-button">&times;</span>
                                <h2>Choose the desired quantity: </h2>
                                <input type="number" id="numOfProduct" min="1" max="3">
                                <button class="confirmButton" data-id="0"> Confirm </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                      <div class="container">
                hello
                <div class="descriptionProduct">
                    description
                    <div class="quantityProduct">
                        <button class="productButton" title="add to cart">add to cart</button>
                        <div class="modal">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <span class="close-button">&times;</span>
                                <h2>Choose the desired quantity: </h2>
                                <input type="number" id="numOfProduct" min="1" max="3">
                                <button class="confirmButton" data-id="1"> Confirm </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                      <div class="container">
                hello
                <div class="descriptionProduct">
                    description
                    <div class="quantityProduct">
                        <button class="productButton" title="add to cart">add to cart</button>
                        <div class="modal">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <span class="close-button">&times;</span>
                                <h2>Choose the desired quantity: </h2>
                                <input type="number" id="numOfProduct" min="1" max="3">
                                <button class="confirmButton" data-id="2"> Confirm </button>  
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: In the first console.log it prints the right values. data is not empty.

Comment: I edited my post saying that you could maybe try to be more specific with your selectors. We can't help you more than that since we don't have acces to all your codebase. Your JS and Html code is correct as you can see. The problem is somewhere else. Perhaps my recommandation (since my Edit) can be your solution. Hope it will help ;)

Answer (score 0):

- Don't put **functions inside loops**
- **Button should be `type="button"`** (otherwise by default is type `"submit"`)
- **Don't create duplicated IDs**. Never use/create the same repeated IDs - like i.e: inside template engine for loops.
- **Never use Event.target** (unless you really know what you're doing) Use [Event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) instead <sup>*</sup>.

Than here's some minor improvement of your JS code:

```js
function getProductId(ev) {
  const id = ev.currentTarget.dataset.id;
  console.log(id);
}

const confirmButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".section-products .confirmButton"); 
confirmButtons.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", getProductId));
```

<sup>*</sup> Here's just a small example to demonstrate the ***donts*** of *"don't use Event.target"*

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
  console.log(`
    target: ${ev.target.dataset.id}
    currentTarget: ${ev.currentTarget.dataset.id}
  `);
});
```

```css
.icon-lol:after { content: "\1F608"; font-style: normal; }
```

```html
<button type="button" data-id="101">CLICK-ME <i class="icon-lol"></i> &larr; or this guy</button>
```

Comment: I followed your tips but it still doesn't work as I expected.  
Right now my code in js is this 
`
function addProduct(ev) {
const id = ev.currentTarget.dataset.id;
console.log(id);
... 

}
let confirmButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".section-products .confirmButton");
confirmButtons.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", addProduct));
`